# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVE react app android request

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs

I publish my project react app in at ISS. My project work very well, but when I tried use in mobile android, request don't works.

return just net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. I don't know, but in mobile XIAOMI work.. samsung for example not.

I'm using axios, but i trying with fetch too.

Any can help me?

I tried request on mobile android and return net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED